# Is there a way to specify 'weight' for fonts, in Android?

Tags: android, android-fonts

Either programmatically or in XML, is there a way to set font weight in Android?

Comment: You can add a family of fonts to your assets folder, and from there instantiate them. You could for example add HelveticaNeue-Light, HelveticaNeue-Bold, HelveticaNeue-Thin...

Comment: Create different values folder. And add Dimen in each folder. And use @deepak code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
              getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
```

create dimensions folder like this res/values/dimensions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <dimen name="textsize">8sp</dimen>

 </resources>
```